# Simplest optimization method for specific nonlinear function

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, parameter-estimation

I want to find the best parameters for a model given a set of measurements. The model has the function
$y = a + b \cdot \frac{x-c}{x+c}$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ are the parameters that must be optimized and $ x \in \mathbb{C}$ is the model input and $ y \in \mathbb{C}$ is the model output. I have acquired a set of $N$ measurements with known $(x_i, y_i)$. Now I would like to find the best set of $(a, b, c)$ to match the measurements as close as possible.

So that would boil down to minimizing $f$, where

$$
f = \sum_i \left\lVert a + b \cdot \frac{x_i-c}{x_i+c} - y_i \right\rVert 
$$

No constraints are given on $(a, b, c)$.

I am currently a bit clueless about proceeding with this optimization problem. Is there a particular method that suits well for this?

Kind regards,
Peter

Comment: If it is a nonsmooth optimization problem, I would look for some proximal gradient method first. The hardest part is to calculate the proximal operator applied to that summands, but maybe some reduction is possible to be done.

Comment: @PeterO. This is a problem of nonlinear regression. They are many variant of methods which require initial guessing of the parameters to start some iterative process. For example see : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonlinearLeastSquaresFitting.html or : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares . A key point is the Initial parameter estimates. Various appoaches are implemented in the specialised sofwares. One cannot give judicious advice without more information about the kind of data (distribution, shape, ...) You should joint to your question a representative example of data.

Comment: It is a non-smooth non-convex optimization in however only three unknowns. For such a problem deterministic optimization can be a proper choice (the branch and bound method in particular), which can find a guaranteed global minimum without the need of any starting values. You only need to restrict $a,b,c$ to some box, which could be found possibly from the dataset $\{x_i,y_i\}$. The branch and bound method is implemented for example in the BARON solver, which is up to 10 unknowns free (https://minlp.com/baron-solver). If you put your dataset here, I can give you the corresponding BARON script.

Comment: Are the data and parameter values, complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, they are complex. Thanks so far for all the suggestions. I will dig a bit deeper in them :)